# Backbone Route parameter not working without hash

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, backbone.js

I have problem routing my app to a route like :

```
"list/:id": 'list'
```

My webpage goes to, eg list/subpage and I have a blank page.
It is well redirected when I use an hash, like #list/subpage

My Backbone start :

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
```

My .htaccess :

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php [L]
</ifModule>
```

What could be wrong ? Tell me if you need more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how routing works on the frontend. Without the hash, the application is trying to reach a route on the server that doesn't exist. The hash is what specifies that the routing is going to take place on the client instead.

This might give you a better idea: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/

Comment: I should be redirected to the root, right ? Even if i am in a "subfolder " ?

Comment: I don't quite follow, sorry. If you try to hit the wrong directory on the server, you won't be correctly redirected unless the server is configured to do so.

Comment: When I hit /list, it's working. But when I hit /list/ or /list/[something], Im not redirected to the index

Comment: Yes, because it's not the clients job to do that. Anything before the hash will be processed by the server. If there's not something on the server to handle that redirection, you won't get your desired results.